# State not updating as expected useing React-Native, useState, and setInterval

Tags: react-native, expo, setinterval, use-state

There is a count down timer activated by a play/pause button.  `setInterval` is called in `run` passing in two functions `countDown` and `vibrate`.  `countDown` decrements the state of the timer.

Within `vibrate` I want the phone to vibrate when the timer reaches a certain number, however, within `vibrate` "timer" is always 1500 until the pause button is pressed, and when play is pressed again "timer" is the value it had when paused.

In `clockify` which displays the time, "timer" is the current value of "timer" and the timer counts down.

I've read for hours here trying to fix this (which seems like a closure issue?) but could not come up with a solution, other than refactoring this into a class and use `this.state`

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons'

let intervalId = null 

export default function App() {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(1500),
        [running, setRunning] = useState(false)
  
  const reset = () => {
    setTimer(1500)
    setRunning(false)
    clearInterval(intervalId)
  }
  const playPauseIcon = () => {
    if (!running) {
      return ( <FontAwesome name="play" style={styles.icons} /> )
    } else {
      return ( <FontAwesome name="pause" style={styles.icons} /> )
    }
  }
  const playPause = () => {
    if (!running) {
      setRunning(true)
      run()
    } else {
      setRunning(false)
      this.clearInterval(intervalId)
    }
  }
  const run = () => {
    intervalId = setInterval(consolidateFunc, 1000)
  }
  const consolidateFunc = () => {
    countDown()
    vibrate()
  }
  const countDown = () => {
    console.log("timer in countDown" + timer) // always logs 1500, 1500, 1500 until the play/pause button is pressed
    setTimer(timer => timer - 1)
  }
  const vibrate = () => {
    console.log("timer in buzz " + timer) // always logs 1500, 1500, 1500 until the play/pause button is pressed
    if (timer < 1496) {
      // vibrate
      console.log("vibrate")
      clearInterval(intervalId)
    }
  }
  const clockify = () => {
    console.log("timer in clock " + timer) //counts down 1500, 1499, 1498, etc.
    const minutes = Math.floor(timer / 60),
          seconds = timer % 60
    if (seconds < 10 && minutes < 10) {
      return "0" + minutes + ":" + "0" + seconds;
    } else if (seconds < 10) {
      return minutes + ":" + "0" + seconds;
    } else {
      return minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.controls}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={playPause} style={styles.reset}>{playPauseIcon()}</TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.reset} onPress={reset}>
          <FontAwesome name="undo" style={styles.icons} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <Text style={styles.status}>Time Remaining</Text>
      <Text style={styles.timeLeft}>{clockify()}</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  status: {
    fontSize: 30,
    paddingTop: 20
  },
  timeLeft: {
    fontSize: 30
  },
  controls: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  icons: {
    fontSize: 25,
    color: "black",
    paddingLeft: 10
  },
  reset: {
    paddingTop: 15,
    paddingRight: 5,
    paddingLeft: 5
  }
});
```

View on snack: https://snack.expo.io/R1ST9Ct4U

I can make it work using a class but I would prefer not to if possible, it seems like there should be a way.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons'

const defaultState = {timer: 1500, running: false };

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = defaultState
    this.reset = this.reset.bind(this)
    this.clockify = this.clockify.bind(this);
    this.run = this.run.bind(this);
    this.consolidateFunc = this.consolidateFunc.bind(this)
    this.countDown = this.countDown.bind(this)
    this.vibrate = this.vibrate.bind(this)
    this.playPauseIcon= this.playPauseIcon.bind(this)
    this.playPause = this.playPause.bind(this)
  }
  reset() {
    this.setState(defaultState)
    clearInterval(this.intervalId)
  }
  clockify() {
    const minutes = Math.floor(this.state.timer / 60);
    const seconds = this.state.timer % 60;
    if (seconds < 10 && minutes < 10) {
      return "0" + minutes + ":" + "0" + seconds;
    } else if (seconds < 10) {
      return minutes + ":" + "0" + seconds;
    } else {
      return minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
  }
  run() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.consolidateFunc, 1000); 
  }
  consolidateFunc() {   
    this.countDown();
    this.vibrate();
  }
  countDown() {
    console.log("timer in countDown: " + this.state.timer)
    this.setState({ timer: this.state.timer - 1 });
  }
  vibrate() {
    console.log("timer in vibrate: " + this.state.timer)
    if (this.state.timer < 1496) {
      // vibrate
      console.log("vibrate")
      clearInterval(this.intervalId)
    } 
  }
  playPauseIcon() {
    if (!this.state.running) {
      return ( <FontAwesome name="play" style={styles.icons} /> )
    } else {
      return ( <FontAwesome name="pause" style={styles.icons} /> )
    }
  }
  playPause() {
    if (!this.state.running) {
      this.setState({ running: true });
      this.run();
    } else {
      this.setState({ running: false });
      clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.controls}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.playPause} style={styles.reset}>{this.playPauseIcon()}</TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.reset} onPress={this.reset}>
            <FontAwesome name="undo" style={styles.icons} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.status}>Time Remaining</Text>
        <Text style={styles.timeLeft}>{this.clockify()}</Text>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  status: {
    fontSize: 30,
    paddingTop: 20
  },
  timeLeft: {
    fontSize: 30
  },
  controls: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  icons: {
    fontSize: 25,
    color: "black",
    paddingLeft: 10
  },
  reset: {
    paddingTop: 15,
    paddingRight: 5,
    paddingLeft: 5
  }
});
```

View as class on snack: https://snack.expo.io/mIG7TqB4I

Answer (score 1):

I took a walk and the answer came to me.

The answer was to to eliminate the `consolidateFunc`, pass `countDown` to `setInterval`, move the code inside `vibrate` into `useEffect`, delete `vibrate`.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons'

let intervalId = null 

export default function App() {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(1500),
        [running, setRunning] = useState(false)
  
  const reset = () => {
    setTimer(1500)
    setRunning(false)
    clearInterval(intervalId)
  }
  const playPauseIcon = () => {
    if (!running) {
      return ( <FontAwesome name="play" style={styles.icons} /> )
    } else {
      return ( <FontAwesome name="pause" style={styles.icons} /> )
    }
  }
  const playPause = () => {
    if (!running) {
      setRunning(true)
      run()
    } else {
      setRunning(false)
      clearInterval(intervalId)
    }
  }
  const run = () => {
    intervalId = setInterval(countDown, 1000)
  }
  const countDown = () => {
    setTimer(timer => timer - 1)
  }
  const clockify = () => {
    //console.log("timer in clock " + timer)
    const minutes = Math.floor(timer / 60),
          seconds = timer % 60
    if (seconds < 10 && minutes < 10) {
      return "0" + minutes + ":" + "0" + seconds;
    } else if (seconds < 10) {
      return minutes + ":" + "0" + seconds;
    } else {
      return minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("timer in useEffect " + timer)
    if (timer < 1496) {
      // vibrate
      console.log("vibrate")
      clearInterval(intervalId)
    }
  })

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.controls}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={playPause} style={styles.reset}>{playPauseIcon()}</TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.reset} onPress={reset}>
          <FontAwesome name="undo" style={styles.icons} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <Text style={styles.status}>Time Remaining</Text>
      <Text style={styles.timeLeft}>{clockify()}</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  status: {
    fontSize: 30,
    paddingTop: 20
  },
  timeLeft: {
    fontSize: 30
  },
  controls: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  icons: {
    fontSize: 25,
    color: "black",
    paddingLeft: 10
  },
  reset: {
    paddingTop: 15,
    paddingRight: 5,
    paddingLeft: 5
  }
});
```